# Reading words and storing them in 2-D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, word-count

I am trying to write a program that reads lines word by word and puts each word in an array (later I want to do some operations on those words but this isn't an issue now) and in the output there should be a number of words in each line. For example:

```
input:
good morning my neighbors!
how are you?

output:
4
3
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char word[100];
    char wordArray[100][100];
    int count = 0;
    for(;scanf("%s", word)!=EOF;)
    {
        strcpy(wordArray[count], word);
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d", count);

    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me just 7 in the output (number of all words on both lines). If I put `printf` function inside the `for` loop then I get `1234567` as an output. How do I make it count words on one line and print it then set the count to zero and start over on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `fgets` or `getline` because `scanf` reads word by word not all words in one line.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
    char wordArray[SIZE][SIZE];
    int count[SIZE];
    int c = 0;
    while(fgets( wordArray[c], SIZE, stdin) && c < SIZE)
    { 
        for(int i = 0; wordArray[c][i] != '\0' ; i++) {
            // remove enter character at the end of each line, not necessary in this case but mabe later when you work with all works
            wordArray[c][strcspn ( wordArray[c], "\n" )] = '\0'; 
            if (wordArray[c][i] == ' ') {
                 count[c]++; // increase the number of words if we meet space character
            }
        }
        c++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) //print all the counts
        printf("%d", count[i] + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentaly edited your code, I rolled it back immediatly.

Comment: @anastaciu you can edit if there are some grammar faults in my answer. Thanks

Comment: yeah, it can be done with fgets. I was trying to make it with just scanf. but there should be ```printf("%d\n", count[i]+1);``` at the end as counting just by using spaces doesn't count the last word

Comment: Thanks for your trust, but this time it was an accident, I was trying to edit mine.

Answer (score 1):

It gives you 7 because `count` is never reseted. I would store the `count`s to print later, this could be done with an array, the `1234567` is normal if it's inside the cycle it will print `count` for every word scaned. If you use `"%d "` with a space you'll have  `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`.

The following program takes 5 lines from the user, counts the words in each line and stores the counts in an array, using `scanf` and `strtok` to count the words:

[**Demo**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/ShamefulTediousBetaversion)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 5
#define LENGTH 100

int main()
{
    char word[LENGTH];
    char wordArray[SIZE][LENGTH];
    int count[SIZE] = {0}; //array to store the counts
    const char delimiter[] = " ";
    char *token;
    printf("Insert %d phrases:\n", SIZE);
    // %99[^\n] specifier also to avoid buffer overflow and read till newline
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE && scanf(" %99[^\n]", wordArray[i]) == 1; i++)
    {
        strcpy(word, wordArray[i]);
        token = strtok(word, delimiter);
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            count[i]++;
            token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {//print all the counts
        printf("string %d - \"%s\" - ", i + 1, wordArray[i]);
        printf("%d words\n", count[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @OrangeBike If you are going to use EOF it's more complicated because the cycle only ends when you send the EOF signal, with scanf is hard to tell where the \n is, I'll take a look at it and get back to you.

Comment: @OrangeBike, so I see you already have a satisfying answer, nonetheless, since I said I would, I leave with an alternative still using scanf,

Answer (score 1):

Here I used `fgets` to get line by line from `stdin`. 
The code actually count the spaces in the line and add 1 to them. I also did NOT used `string.h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
  int i=0;
  char lines[SIZE][SIZE];
  int count[SIZE]={0};
  while(i<SIZE){
    fgets(lines[i], SIZE, stdin);
    if (lines[i][0]=='\n') break;
    i++;
  }

  for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
    char *x=lines[j];
    while(*x!='\0') {
      if (*x==' ') count[j]++;
      x++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", count[j]+1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```